# Solaris spoof mac impossible

Tags: solaris, mac, netmask

I need to spoof the MAC address in Solaris 10, running in a ESXi VM. The MAC I need is outside the range permitted by vSphere.

So I add an "ether" entry to /etc/hostname.e1000g0 so the file says

abchost01

ether 1:2:3:4:5:6

and reboot. To my horror, the netmask is now ff000000. It was fffffe00 before.
so I add

netmask 255.255.254.0

to /etc/hostname.e1000g0

and reboot. ifconfig -a looks fine at first glance, but can't ping the IP. To my horror, the broadcast address is now 10.255.255.255, instead of 10.182.217.255.

What can I do to set the MAC addy with config files in Solaris 10? I have tried a rc.local approach using SMF to fire it off. What an absolute pain it is to work with SMF. I'd rather do this using config files. In Windows and Linux I would have done this in 10 seconds - but Solaris has beaten me up badly. Help please.

Comment: try put hostname and ether in one line. The system thinks 10.0.0.0/8 network is a class A network so that's the mask. You can override this in /etc/netmasks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at this in a VM earlier. I noticed that when I had

```
hostname
ether 10:20:30:40:50:60
```

in /etc/hostname.e1000g0, when the system booted it logged an error for

> Sep 15 20:10:46 hostname svc.startd[7]: [ID 748625 daemon.error] network/physical
>   :default misconfigured: transitioned to maintenance (see 'svcs -xv' for details)

Looking at the e1000g0 interface we see

```
e1000g0: flags=1000843<BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 2
    inet 192.168.1.68 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    ether 0:c:29:25:22:f8
```

As you say this looks normal but it's not, it's not `UP` so it won't respond to pings etc. This would explain your horrors!

To change the mac address you have to put the hostname and ether address on the same line

```
hostname ether 10:20:30:40:50:60
```

then after a reboot looking at e1000g0 we see

```
e1000g0: flags=1000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 2
    inet 192.168.1.68 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    ether 10:20:30:40:50:60
```

which is what you want.

Comment: That worked. All the options one line does this trick. Ok, so does anyone know where this /etc/hostname.{nic} format documented? I have been googling for days. Or perhaps this is just "common knowledge" for Solaris admins....

Comment: @Jepper: I haven't found it documented anywhere, in fact the only documentation I've found is http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0916/ipconfig-13/index.html